# How to secure a RESTful Web Service exposed by a web API?

Tags: asp.net, security, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have REST web services exposed by APIs controllers in my ASP.NET Application. These services are useful for me to synchronize my business layer with my view layer.
Now I want to make them more secure, because I feel like all my data is exposed and that anyone can have access to them, if only he types the http url of the web service. Is there any username/password security mecanism for my web services? Or is this done via a certain configuration to IIS?

Comment: oauth isa very secure way; here is some [info](http://oauth.net/code/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to create your own security mechanism then it would not be to hard to authenticate using tokens in the http header. For example, you could use a public/private key scheme and hash a few items that change frequently such as DateTime and input parameters and the resource url itself.

.Net provides ways to place your security checks prior to reaching your service methods so you don't even have to check the token in the http header in each of your methods. They will only be invoked if the request is authenticated.